# Calculating the price difference between two days

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the following table called Stores:

```
Date        |  Store  |  Price
2018-05-02  |  ABC    |  0.91
2018-05-02  |  DEF    |  0.81
2018-05-03  |  ABC    |  0.92
2018-05-03  |  DEF    |  0.83
2018-05-05  |  ABC    |  0.91
2018-05-05  |  DEF    |  0.85
```

I am trying to write a query that for a given store, will output the price, the price of the previous day, as well as the difference in price between two days and the price gain (which is a percentage). The output should look like the following:

```
 Date        |  Store  |  Price  |  PrevPrice  |  Change  |  Gain
 2018-05-03  |  ABC    |  0.92   |  0.91       |  0.01    |  1.086956522
 2018-05-05  |  ABC    |  0.91   |  0.92       |  -0.01   |  -1.098901099
 2018-05-03  |  DEF    |  0.83   |  0.81       |  0.02    |  2.409638554
 2018-05-05  |  DEF    |  0.85   |  0.83       |  0.02    |  2.352941176
```

The first date should not be in the output since it doesn't have a preceding date.
I have the following query which gets the PrevPrice using lag():

```
select * 
from (
    select "Date", store, price, lag(price) over (partition by code order by "Date") as PrevPrice from Stores
) s where PrevPrice is not null;
```

I am not sure how I can calculate the price difference between two days or the price gain. More specifically, I don't know what methods I can use the calculate the price difference. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there. Just subtract lag(price) from price:

```
SELECT Date, Store, Price, PrevPrice, Price - PrevPrice AS Change, (Price - PrevPrice) / PrevPrice * 100 AS Gain
FROM (
    SELECT Date, Store, Price, LAG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Store ORDER BY Date) AS PrevPrice
    FROM t
) AS x
WHERE PrevPrice IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Was just creating this as a fiddle so you may as well add it to your answer: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dxonYCNpAyNuS9tvfxB8F3/0

Comment: Is there any way that I can round down the 'Gain' value to the nearest whole number to two decimal places? E.g. 2.352941176 should be displayed as 2.00 and -1.098901099 as -1.00.

Comment: This seems to work `SELECT CAST(FLOOR(2.352941176) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))`